# How can I enable mod_rewrite on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: apache2, 15.04, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to enable `mod_rewrite` on my new server. I installed LAMP and configured the rest using webmin, but I can't run `mod_rewrite`. I get the URL Not Found page when I make any changes in configs like `000default.conf` or `apache.conf`.

> ```
> sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
> ```
>
> Search for `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` and add the following lines directly below:
>
> ```
> <Directory "/var/www/html">
>     AllowOverride All
> </Directory>
> ```
>
> This method doesn't work. My sites are in `/var/www/domainname` not in `/var/www/html/domainname`

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` - empty file

When I add

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
```

To the virtual server configuration file I get the Forbidden page (no permission) for every URL, even for top domain.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it thanks to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868785/mod-rewrite-wasnt-working-so-while-fixing-it-getting-403-forbidden)

Just this

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory "/var/www/">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/yourdomain.com.conf` is sufficient